# Passing values from client to server and back to client, asynchronously

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I've been trying to figure this problem out for quite a while. I know JavaScript is client side scripting and PHP is server-side scripting, but is it possible to pass a browsers epoch time into a PHP script to run some calculations then return geoJSON data based on the results; all asynchronously?

The function I want to pass to the PHP script is something like:

```
function retreiveUTC() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var browserUTC = Math.floor(now)/1000.0;  // this returns epoch time of the browser
}
```

Then I would like to take the epoch time that is generated from the function and pass it to a php script to determine what JSON file to return.

For example I will have the following files residing on the server:

```
1352188536.JSON
1352187536.JSON
1352177536.JSON
```

And I want to retrieve the one that is closest to the browsers epoch results. Thank you in advance.

Updated code below:

not sure what I am doing wrong, but I am getting success from the ajax call but the return value is undefined.

ajax stuff:

```
    $.post ('timezone.php',
    {
        epochTime: browserUTC
    }, 
    function (result) {
       //do someting to result
    }, "json");

    var browserUTC = new Date().getTime();

    $.post ('timezone.php',
    {
        epochTime: browserUTC
    }, 
    function (result,status) {
   //display file name returned by PHP
        alert(result.file + "\n" + status);
   //console.log('test');
    });
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    $epochTime = round($_POST['epochTime'] / 1000);
    $res= array();
    $res['file'] = $epochTime . '.JSON';
    return json_encode($res);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about asynchronous requests. You can send an AJAX request to your php script and get the respective JSON data and do the processing. You've to change the design.

First when the page is requested, send normal data (other than JSON) and as soon as the javascript file is loaded there on the client side, you can invoke the function and at the end of the function, just use an AJAX request to send the browser time back to another php script which will fetch the corresponding JSON file and give to the client.

Use jquery library to do AJAX requests in an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it is done via standard AJAX call. For example, if you are using jQuery:

```
 $.post ('pathToPHPScript.php', {epochTime: browserUTC}, function (result) {
       //do someting to result
    }, "json");
```

In PHP script you can retrieve the value of epoch time like standard POST variable:

```
$epochTime = $_POST['epochTime'];
//do required calculations
```

So PHP has bult-in [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function that help to make a JSON-encoded string out of array. If you pass it an array, you can then retrieve in jQuery:

```
//PHP
$res= array();
$res['file'] = $epochTime . '.JSON';
return json_encode($res);
```

and in jQuery's callback function cited above:

```
 $.post ('pathToPHPScript.php', {epochTime: browserUTC}, function (result) {
       //display file name returned by PHP
       console.log(result.file);
    });
```

Comment: I am able to pass the epoch value to the php script and process it but `console.log(result.file);` is showing undefined. Am I missing somehting? It seems the PHP script isn't returning the value. Thank you.

Comment: This is because "json" parameter needed to be added to $.post function for proper JSON handling. Check out the edited code.

Comment: Is this suppose to return the file as an JSON object or just the filename?

Comment: it should return the filename as JSON object.

Comment: I updated my code above. I am still getting undefined. Thank you.